# Step by step solution to these derivations

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I will write test tomorow and I'm stuck at few derivation examples. Unfortunatelly, teacher don't gave me a solution to these examples. I have no problem with simpler derivations.

Calculate first derivation of following functions and specify the domain of derivation:

$f_1(x)=(\arctan\frac{3x}{2x^2-8})^2+\frac{7}{9}$

$f_2(x)=6^{x^{3}}\sqrt[8]{x-x^2}+\arcsin\frac{2x-2}{4}$

$f_3(x)=\cot(4x)+\log_7(2x)$

$f_4(x)=\frac{2x\cos(3x)}{e^{-2x}}+x^{x^{2}}$

I think I just have problem with precedence of operations. I will be very grateful if someone post me straightforward and step by step solution to these examples.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: you Need the power and the chain rule
$$2\,{1\arctan \left( 3\,{\frac {x}{2\,{x}^{2}-8}} \right)  \left( 3\,
 \left( 2\,{x}^{2}-8 \right) ^{-1}-12\,{\frac {{x}^{2}}{ \left( 2\,{x}
^{2}-8 \right) ^{2}}} \right)  \left( 9\,{\frac {{x}^{2}}{ \left( 2\,{
x}^{2}-8 \right) ^{2}}}+1 \right) ^{-1}}
$$
the first derivative of $$\frac{3x}{2x^2-8}$$ is given by $$3\, \left( 2\,{x}^{2}-8 \right) ^{-1}-12\,{\frac {{x}^{2}}{ \left( 2\,
{x}^{2}-8 \right) ^{2}}}
$$ and the derivative of $$arctan\left(\frac{3x}{2x^2-8}\right)$$ as 
$${1 \left( 3\, \left( 2\,{x}^{2}-8 \right) ^{-1}-12\,{\frac {{x}^{2}}{
 \left( 2\,{x}^{2}-8 \right) ^{2}}} \right)  \left( 9\,{\frac {{x}^{2}
}{ \left( 2\,{x}^{2}-8 \right) ^{2}}}+1 \right) ^{-1}}
$$

and the derivative with the power $2$ is given by $$2\,{1\arctan \left( 3\,{\frac {x}{2\,{x}^{2}-8}} \right)  \left( 3\,
 \left( 2\,{x}^{2}-8 \right) ^{-1}-12\,{\frac {{x}^{2}}{ \left( 2\,{x}
^{2}-8 \right) ^{2}}} \right)  \left( 9\,{\frac {{x}^{2}}{ \left( 2\,{
x}^{2}-8 \right) ^{2}}}+1 \right) ^{-1}}
$$

for 2) we need the product, chain and the power rule
$$3\,{6}^{{x}^{3}}{x}^{2}\ln  \left( 6 \right) \sqrt [8]{-{x}^{2}+x}+1/8
\,{{6}^{{x}^{3}} \left( -2\,x+1 \right)  \left( -{x}^{2}+x \right) ^{-
{\frac {7}{8}}}}+{\frac {1}{\sqrt {-{x}^{2}+2\,x+3}}}
$$

for 3) we have $$-4-4\, \left( \cot \left( 4\,x \right)  \right) ^{2}+{\frac {1}{x\ln 
 \left( 7 \right) }}
$$

and for the last one we get $$2\,{\frac {\cos \left( 3\,x \right) }{{{\rm e}^{-2\,x}}}}-6\,{\frac {x
\sin \left( 3\,x \right) }{{{\rm e}^{-2\,x}}}}+4\,{\frac {x\cos
 \left( 3\,x \right) }{{{\rm e}^{-2\,x}}}}+{x}^{{x}^{2}} \left( 2\,x
\ln  \left( x \right) +x \right) 
$$

Comment: Thank you for great explanation!

Comment: you are a delete king Mr. Fisher

Comment: i am impressed...(+1)